# D3js not removing element on exit

Tags: d3.js

I have a function that render text element with tspan. My problem is that draw() function append new text element and not removing the old one when redraw.

```
function draw(params) {
    let g = d3.select(`#msr_${Id}`);

    const value = params.Value;

    const [a, b, c, d, x, y] = params.Matrix;
    const matrix = [a, b, c, d, x + params.Coord[0], y + params.Coord[1]];

    let text = g
      .append("text")
      .attr("font-weight", params.Font.Weight)
      .attr("font-size", params.Font.Size)
      .attr("font-family", params.Font.Family)
      .attr("text-decoration", params.Font.Decoration)
      .attr("transform", `matrix(${matrix})`)
      .selectAll("text");

    let desc = text.select("tspan").data([params.MsrName]);
    desc
      .enter()
      .append("tspan")
      .text((d) => d);

    let textValue = text.select("tspan").data([value]);
    textValue
      .enter()
      .append("tspan")
      .text((d) => d);

    g.exit().remove();
  }
```

Comment: Are you hoping to exit the tspans or remove/replace/update the previous parent text element? If the former, the creation of a new parent `text` each draw cycle means that everything will be entered and nothing exited (as the parent is new and has no children to exit).

Comment: I'd like to update/replace tspan. I've tried to add text.exit().remove() or desc.exit().remove() but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this creating svg group manually.

```
 <g id={`msr_${Id}`}>
      <text id={`msr_txt_${Id}`}>
        <tspan id={`msr_desc_${Id}`}></tspan>
        <tspan id={`msr_value_${Id}`}></tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
```

Here's code:

```
let g = d3.select(`#msr_${Id}`);

    let text = g
      .select(`#msr_txt_${Id}`)
   

    let desc = text.select(`#msr_desc_${Id}`).data([name]);
    desc.text((d) => d);
    desc.exit().remove();
    
    let textValue = text.select(`#msr_value_${Id}`).data([value]);
    textValue.text((d) => d);
    textValue.exit().remove();
    
    g.exit().remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that d3 is the best option to apply here, but it can be done.
This solution is only to make it work, its not by any means optimized.

```
function draw(params) {
    // I am assuming that you have access to the svg

    const value = params.Value;

    const [a, b, c, d, x, y] = params.Matrix;
    const matrix = [a, b, c, d, x + params.Coord[0], y + params.Coord[1]];

    
    // #1. make sure that the container exists
    if (!d3.select(`#msr_${Id}`).node()) {
        d3.select(svg).append('g')
            .attr('id', `#msr_${Id}`)
            .append('text')
            .attr('id', `#msr_desc_${Id}`);
    }    

    // #2 - update the text element
    const text = d3.select(`#msr_desc_${Id}`)
      .attr("font-weight", params.Font.Weight)
      .attr("font-size", params.Font.Size)
      .attr("font-family", params.Font.Family)
      .attr("text-decoration", params.Font.Decoration)
      .attr("transform", `matrix(${matrix})`);

    // #3 - update the tspan elements
    let desc = text.selectAll("tspan")
        .data([[params.MsrName, `msr_desc_${Id}`], [value, `msr_value_${Id}`]]);

    desc
      .enter()
      .append("tspan")
      .merge(desc)
      .attr('id', (d) => d[1])
      .text((d) => d[0]);

    desc.exit().remove();
  }
```